# Python search with Google's Customsearch API

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-api

I'm trying to configure in a good way my search script using Google's Search API.

I have some keywords in my input file from whom I'd like to get first 10 results. When I'm searching them manually - the results are extremely different (expected).

Doing it with API - I'm getting really strange output.
Did anyone have similar problem before ?

Maybe anyone would give me some tips how to configure search engine ?

I've set: `*.google.com/*`

Python script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from googleapiclient.discovery import build

def main():
    service = build('customsearch', 'v1', developerKey="key")

    file = open("./data.csv", "r")
    keys = []

    for key in file.readlines():
        keys.append(key)
    keys.sort()

    for keyword in keys:
        print(u"\nRESULTS SEARCH FOR: %s" % str(keyword))

        res = service.cse().list(
            q=keyword,
            cx='cx',
            num=10,
            safe= 'off',
        ).execute()

        if not 'items' in res:
            print (u"No result !!\nres is: %s" % str(res))
        else:
            with open("results_data.txt", "w") as f:
                for item in res['items']:
                    print('\n%s:\n\t%s' % (item['title'], item['link']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Google search results are tailored based on a lot of criteria, what you get for a search and  what I get can be completely different, what is *strange* about your output?

Comment: I got your point. All I mean is that the results I get are always with the domain "http://www.google.com/." @PadraicCunningham